# Deploying Angular 2 app to Google App Engine

Tags: angular, flask

Please I am wondering if anyone have a very good tutorial on how to deploy and Angular 2 app to Google App Engine.

Deploying an angular 2 app to Firebase is quite easy and straight forward, but i don't seem to know how to do so with the Google App engine

Answer (score 0):

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-cardboard-viewer/index.html

This might be what you need. It's not exactly a verbatim deployment guide, but it comes close and has several clues to arriving at an Angular 2 + NodeJS app engine environment.

Comment: Thanks Alap, exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

Had some similar question and couple of hiccups, but finally found a way to deploy it on App Engine and Firebase. [Here is the blog entry](https://jaykhimani.blogspot.com/2016/10/deploying-angular-2-app-with-angular.html). Also read Elad Elram's comment on the blog on how to handle refresh and routing well.

Comment: interesting blog. thanks. was able to make this work